# How does the "volume" argument work in docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, mount

I have these following lines on my .gitlabci file :

```
- echo "$PWD"
- ls -l "$PWD"
- docker run --volume "$PWD":/code debian:stable ls -l /code
```

And following is the output:

```
$ echo "$PWD" 
/builds/ben/project 

$ ls -l "$PWD" total 52
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           946 Feb 19 14:53 ChangeLog
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           294 Feb 19 14:53 INSTALL
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          4341 Feb 19 14:53 Jenkinsfile
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           353 Feb 19 14:53 README.md
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           535 Feb 19 14:53 TODO 
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Feb 19 14:53 application
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Feb 19 14:53 library 
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Feb 19 14:53 public 
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Feb 19 14:53 tests 

$ docker run --volume "$PWD":/code debian:stable ls -l /code 
total 0
```

Following is my .gitlabci file:

```
code_quality:
  image: docker:stable

  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

  allow_failure: true

  services:
    - docker:dind

  script:
    - echo "$PWD"
    - ls -l "$PWD"
    - docker run --volume "$PWD":/code debian:stable ls -l /code
```

And finally the config.toml of my runner:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "test"
  url = "http://docker.int.com:1040/"
  token = "*************"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/cache"]
    extra_hosts = ["mygitlab.com:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

I don't understand why the last command doesn't display the content of my $PWD directory (/builds/ben/project). My volume doesn't seem to be mounted successfully but I get no error.

Comment: Is Gitlab itself running in Docker?

Comment: yes, gitlab in docker, so is its runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you are using `docker-in-docker` mode.

In this mode `docker` command in pipeline effectively connects to **HOST** machine's docker daemon and sends all commands there. As a result, **host** tries to bind `/builds/ben/project` path into container, but there is no such path. Again, following bind mounts behavior, this folder will be created empty and mapped into containers.

If you are using non-privileged mode (mapping `/var/run/docker.sock`), try switching to using `docker:dind` as a service. In this case daemon will get context from your build job. Otherwise you have to manually copy data into volume.

## UPD

When using `/var/run/docker.sock` you actually pass docker commands unmodified to the daemon, who executes them **in his own context**. That means he uses his file system, not yours (job's). I've managed to bypass this by *manual cloning* sources  into new container with command like

```
git clone ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL} --branch ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} --single-branch /tmp/project
```

Drawback is that you need to install `git` into your images.

This is what gitlab [writes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html):

> Sharing files and directories from the source repo into containers may
>   not work as expected since volume mounting is done in the context of
>   the host machine, not the build container

Comment: I edited my question by adding the full content of my .gitlabci file and the one of my runner configuration

Comment: So that proves my assumption - you are using host's docker daemon through `/var/run/docker.sock`. In this mode your commands pass to host and your job's file system is not available as is